# Get content of a file, throws "host name may be null"

Tags: android

I'm having a trouble getting the content of a file located at a address similar to 
"http:///127.0.0.1:1935/app/unique_id/file.txt". The exception states that the host name
may be null. I think the problem is due to the port.

How do I get the content of the file?

```
        final HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();      
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        InputStream inputStream = timedCall(new Callable<InputStream>() {
            public InputStream call() throws Exception {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                return response.getEntity().getContent();
            };
        }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return inputStream;
```

Comment: It looks like you have one too many slashes after the "http:" in the example URL you provided.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: oh, right.... heh.. that solved my problem... thank you :)

Comment: OK, I'll add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have one too many slashes after the "http:" in the example URL you provided.  There should only be two, as in:
`http://127.0.0.1:1935/app/unique_id/file.txt`